# ng-valid and ng-invalid classes in angular dart forms are no more exposed

Tags: forms, angular, css, dart, angular-dart

Dart: 1.24.2;
Angular: 4.0.0;
I created some CSS rules based on `.ng-valid` and `.ng-invalid` classes in angular forms. But, in last releases, it seems that `ng-valid` and `ng-invalid` classes are no more exposed, so my CSS rules are no more working.
Is it correct? 
if yes, how can I by-pass this change?

Edit1: Test case
I simply generated a brand new project with angular and angular-material in my IDE (WebStorm). It generates a simple todo application. I took the todo_list_component.html and wrapped the whole content with a `<form>` `</form>` tag. In the todo_list_component.dart I have added an import for angular_forms and added formDirectives to the directives list.
Inspecting the form in dartium no `ng-valid` class has been added. The only class added, in my case is: `class="_ngcontent-umj-2"`

Edit2: Shortcut
Not very elegant, but working:

```
<form #form="ngForm" [class.ng-valid]="form.valid" [class.ng-invalid]="!form.valid">
```

Comment: it will be helpful if u share the code or create a plunker demo. thanx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this behavior changed in a recent release of `angular_forms`.

Previously, the `NgControlStatus` directive was included in list of `formDirectives`. However, this caused every component that used forms to pay the price for these host bindings.

Now, if you want the behavior, you need to include `NgControlStatus` explicitly in the `directives` list of the `@Component`.

https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/blob/master/angular_forms/lib/src/directives/ng_control_status.dart#L15

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether they are exposed or not.

At first I would recommend you to work with "Model driven forms" - and set the validation in your component. In my opinion it is better for UnitTests and easier to handle.

and here an example:

Specify CSS (test.component.css) class:

```
.error {
  border: 2px solid red;     
}
```

Component (test.component.ts):

```
imports ...;

@Component({
selector: 'test-component',
templateUrl: 'test.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

 form: FormGroup;

 constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, private auth: AuthService, private toast: ToastController, private fb: FormBuilder) {

 }

 ngOnInit() {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
   email: ['', [
     Validators.required,
     Validators.email]],
   password: ['', [
     Validators.required,
     Validators.minLength(6)]],
 });
}
```

and your template (test.component.html) looks like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="login()" [ngClass]="{'error': !form.valid}">
  *** YOUR FORM DIV'S HERE ***
</form>
```

I don't know if this is working with Dart too. But as Verena commented, we can help you most if you upload some code.